# Android AccountManager.getAuthToken ignoring callback after LoginActivity

Tags: android, accountmanager, android-account

As stated in the question title, the AccountManager will start the LoginActivity from a call to `getAuthToken`, but then it doesn't enter the callback.

What's weird is that it does go to the callback if it has any way of getting an auth token that doesn't require starting the activity (like a cached token or my refresh token mechanism). It's only when returning from the LoginActivity that it doesn't work.

So I'm thinking I'm probably not putting everything in the result bundle that Android is expecting, but what *does* it expect? The docs are pretty thin on that.

Here's the relevant part of the login activity:

```
Bundle result = new Bundle();
if (tokens.hasAccess()) {
    result.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME, account.name);
    result.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_TYPE, account.type);
    result.putString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN, tokens.access);
}
setAccountAuthenticatorResult(result);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
finish();
```

#### Update

My problem is the same as [in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14623255/android-authentication-callback-isnt-called), right down to the delayed invocation of the callback when I relaunch. But his solution doesn't work for me, I already had the `putExtra(KEY_ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATOR_RESPONSE, response)` in my authenticator.

Comment: I recently implemented my the authenticator as well. From what I have seen here. I do not know what went wrong. Can you provide the code where you call getAuthToken?

Comment: I finally figured it out. Instead of `KEY_ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATOR_RESPONSE` I had `KEY_ACCOUNT_MANAGER_RESPONSE`. Just the two look so similar I never noticed when looking for the cause. (Damn you, Eclipse auto complete! :D )

Comment: What's do you set for KEY_ACCOUNT_MANAGER_RESPONSE Parcelable?

Comment: I don't have the relevant code at hand right now but I don't think that one needed to be set at all